# Android is not updating button background color on UI Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, button, android-runonuithread

I am working on an app and trying to update Button background color using on click. What I want to do is,

1) Wait for 0.5 seconds to check answer is right or not. If answer is right, change button color to Green else change it to Red.

2) After button's color change wait for another .5 seconds and than call a function to update question.

Here is my onClick method,

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(totalQuestionsAsked <= 10){
            if(score >= 10)
                score = 10;

            //Setting up button and image
            final Button btnOne = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_one);
            final Button btnTwo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_two);
            final Button btnThree = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_three);
            final Button btnFour = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_four);
            final ImageView flagImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.flag_img);

            final JSONArray country = getFilesArray()[0];
            final JSONArray flag = getFilesArray()[1];

            final View view = v;

            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.btn_one:
                    btnOne.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00b0ff"));
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_two:
                    btnTwo.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00b0ff"));
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_three:
                    btnThree.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00b0ff"));
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_four:
                    btnFour.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00b0ff"));
                    break;
            }

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            final Runnable runnerTwo = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(totalQuestionsAsked <= 10){

                        createCountryElements(flag, country, btnOne, btnTwo, btnThree, btnFour, flagImg);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your total score is: " + String.valueOf(score),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            };

            Runnable runnerOne = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if(view.getTag().equals(flagImg.getTag())){
                        score++;

                        switch (view.getId()){
                            case R.id.btn_one:
                                setButtonGreen(R.id.btn_one);
                                break;
                            case R.id.btn_two:
                                setButtonGreen(R.id.btn_two);
                                break;
                            case R.id.btn_three:
                                setButtonGreen(R.id.btn_three);
                                break;
                            case R.id.btn_four:
                                setButtonGreen(R.id.btn_four);
                                break;
                        }

                    }else{

                        switch (view.getId()){
                            case R.id.btn_one:
                                setButtonRed(R.id.btn_one);
                                break;
                            case R.id.btn_two:
                                setButtonRed(R.id.btn_two);
                                break;
                            case R.id.btn_three:
                                setButtonRed(R.id.btn_three);
                                break;
                            case R.id.btn_four:
                                setButtonRed(R.id.btn_four);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    totalQuestionsAsked++;

                    handler.postDelayed(runnerTwo, 1000);

                }
            };


            handler.postDelayed(runnerOne, 500);


        }

    }
```

So it is just not changing button's background color. Everything else is working properly. Can anyone tell me where is my mistake?

Thank you for helping me. :D

Comment: What can I tell from a quick look at your code is you've change the color in UI thread. So you can move the color change codes in `runOnUIThread{}` block

Comment: @ReazMurshed, So first what I am doing is changing selected button's color. Than I want to wait for 0.5 seconds to check if selected button was right or not and change color according to that. And than after 0.5 seconds, update question. That is what I want to do.

Comment: The cases in the switch are never invoked. Because the View view = v is the view that intercepts the OnClickEvent. And the buttons you provide in the switch loop does not have a OnClickListener. I don't know if you understood what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
btnOne.setBackgroundColor(#00b0ff);
```

will do the trick ;)

Comment: Are you sure that the method is called ? Can you print a `Log` at the same time ?

Comment: I changed back to your given answer and same thing. Nothing is happening. I mean it is not changing color to red or green

Comment: I get it, but can you please make a `toast` or print a `Log` to make sure that the method is called ?

Comment: Which method? On click? Yeah, it is being called everytime plus it is updating question after one second. The only thing is that it is not updating button color.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake, it is not working because I am not changing it to Green. So it is working just not changing to different color. Thank you all for helping me. :D

Comment: Bit of advice, SO is not a port of call for typos, mistakes in code. So when something does not work, do not be running off to SO to post a question "Why does this code not work".  Deep breaths, relax, step away from the computer for a bit, research it.

Comment: I know @t0mm13b. It is like I have been trying to get it fixed for three days and I didn't notice the silliest mistake. :(